# MultipleDatePicker - How to show specific range of years in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multiple-date-picker

I have started learning `Multipledatepicker` and I am making it customize. I have a scenario in which I am taking the calendar to the last date selected for any year/month. Now it works good but now I need to show years in the dropdown from **1960-2028**.

But the official documentation says '**When you select a year it'll re-render the select to always have the same range of the selected year**'. I don't want this to pick years around the selected year.

```
<multiple-date-picker change-year-past="5" change-year-future="10"/>
```

How can I do this?

**Js**

```
 getYearsForSelect = function () {
                    var now = moment(),
                        changeYearPast = Math.max(0, parseInt(scope.changeYearPast, 10) || 0),
                        changeYearFuture = Math.max(0, parseInt(scope.changeYearFuture, 10) || 0),
                        min = moment(scope.month).subtract(changeYearPast, 'year'),
                        max = moment(scope.month).add(changeYearFuture, 'year'),
                        result = [];
                    max.add(1, 'year');
                    for (var m = moment(min); max.isAfter(m, 'YEAR'); m.add(1, 'year')) {
                        if ((!scope.disallowBackPastMonths || (m.isAfter(now, 'year') || m.isSame(now, 'year'))) && (!scope.disallowGoFuturMonths || (m.isBefore(now, 'year') || m.isSame(now, 'year')))) {
                            result.push(m.format('YYYY'));
                        }
                    }
                    return result;
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this :)

```
     getYearsForSelect = function () {
                    // var now = moment(),
                    //     changeYearPast = Math.max(0, parseInt(scope.changeYearPast, 10) || 0),
                    //     changeYearFuture = Math.max(0, parseInt(scope.changeYearFuture, 10) || 0),
                    //     min = moment(scope.month).subtract(changeYearPast, 'year'),
                    //     max = moment(scope.month).add(changeYearFuture, 'year'),
                      var  result = [];
                        // max.add(1, 'year');
                        for (var m = 1960; m<=2028 ; m++) {
                            // if ((!scope.disallowBackPastMonths || (m.isAfter(now, 'year') || m.isSame(now, 'year'))) && (!scope.disallowGoFuturMonths || (m.isBefore(now, 'year') || m.isSame(now, 'year')))) {
                                result.push(m);
                            // }
                        }
                    return result;
                }
```

Comment: @vicJordan if you see the Js file it is placed there. I just customized it according to my need

Comment: yes man, thats why i have made a copy of the js file seperately and using it where ever i require. I also have the orignal one :)